# Not load video embedded with iframe when detect a mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, iframe, loading

In my webpage there is an iframe that embeds a video (vimeo) with a jquery scripts that render the video fullscreen.

The problem is that in mobile devices (specially the apple devices) with a full-witdh video is impossible to push over a link that is obviously over the video player.

My solution is hide the video with a jquery script

```
$('#vimeo').css('display', 'none');
$('#image_video').css('display', 'block');
```

and show an image instead of video that link directly to the vimeo page.

In this way i suppose that also if the video is hidden it will be load in background anyway and for mobile internet connection this is a waste.

My question is, is there a way to prevent the loading of the iframe?

I hope I explained myself. I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I was developing a front-end for a chat in a hosting provider's customer control panel.

Since the chat itself was proprietary, and used AJAX, I had to access its DOM through an iframe, except when you were on a mobile device.

I'd remove the element like this:

```
jQuery("#vimeo").remove();
jQuery("#image_video").css('display','block');
```

That way you avoid non standard attributes and actually just remove the tag from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set iframe src but instead use custom data attribute like

```
<iframe id="iframe1" data-src="http://...." />
```

Then with jQuery set the iframe src if you want to load its content

```
  $('#iframe1').attr( 'src',  $('#iframe1').data('src')  );
```

or Hide it

```
$('#iframe1').hide()
```